# Extract Thumbnail from Video in Ionic App (Android Version)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, video-thumbnails

I am capturing a video using **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture**

Now I want to get a thumbnail from that video.
Also, I have used **com.photokandy.videothumbnail** but I am not getting any result.

I am being stuck in this issue for a long time and highly appreciate any help!

Below is my code snippet:

```
window.PKVideoThumbnail.createThumbnail ('file:///sdcard/ibhool/Video/ibhool.mp4', 'file:///sdcard/ibhool/Video/thumbtest.png', function(prevSucc) {
   return prevImageSuccess(prevSucc);
}, fail);

function prevImageSuccess(succ) {
   alert('success');       
}',
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet worked after i tried installing the plugin multiple times and it just worked finally.But still it does not work on all machines and devices.

Comment: which plugin do you use ?